# Big query Date time in PST

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an issue in bigquery. I have a raw table which holds the created_date(date data type) and created_time(datetime data type) . From the raw table i have created an aggregate table which has a column created_date_pst (timestamp datatype) .the created_date_pst is created from the conversion as-TIMESTAMP(created_date,"America/Los_Angeles") as created_date_pst.

Now the problem is when ever data is inserted from raw table to aggregate table i dont get the correct values or summary of the values (for example sum(calls) ) . i wanted to input the data correctly in aggregate table based on pst timezone. please advise. thank you

Comment: What do you mean by raw table and aggregate table? Can you post  your table schemas and an example of your (SQL?) code that isn't working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.